# Verical DataLabels cuts off in Bar Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I tried the with following demo [enter link description here][1]

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/6snza1fo/`enter code here`

Comment: Hi @debug mode, How do you want to handle the data labels? Do you want to increase the chart height or move the labels down?

Comment: @ppotaczek can is it be possible to increase the y-axis scale value dynamically based on datalabel values to keep the height remain same and datalabel keep inside the chart area.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the required space in an axis units and use `setExtremes` method to apply it:

```
chart: {
  height: 205,
  width: 200,
  background: '#F2F2F2',
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var maxPxY = 0,
        yAxis = this.yAxis[0];

      this.series.forEach(function(s) {
        s.points.forEach(function(p) {
          if (p.dataLabel && p.dataLabel.alignAttr.y < maxPxY) {
            maxPxY = p.dataLabel.alignAttr.y;
          }
        });
      });

      if (maxPxY) {
        yAxis.setExtremes(null, yAxis.toValue(maxPxY));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/amwefro6/1/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toValue

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load